# Can not override UI Component template

Tags: magento2, overrides, uicomponent

Template file
(**app/code/namespace/module/view/adminhtml/ui-component/product_form.xml**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/collapsible2</item>
    </argument>
</form>
```

Does not render **app/code/namespace/module/view/adminhtml/ui-component/templates/collapsible2.xhtml**

But if I

- Copy `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml`
- Modify the template line and make it `app/code/namespace/module/view/adminhtml/ui-component/product_form.xml`,
- Move or delete `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml`

It works.  If I don't move or delete the core file, I can't override the template.

Answer (score 0):

UI Commponent of Extension developers cannot extend this XSD scheme and introduce new components, but can customize existing ones [enter here documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui_comp_guide/bk-ui_comps.html)

Comment: I am not extending the scheme or introducing new components, though alan storm's UI component series shows you how to get around that and add your own components.  I'm simply trying to change the template which they say is eligible here (even though they list some of the directory and file locations wrong): http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ui-components/ui-component.html

Comment: OK, you can probabily run grunt command, for check where is wrong or update your changes, like [here](https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/web_development/9781785888229/6/ch06lvl1sec45/applying-changes-to-bookstore-with-grunt), good luck

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong template path

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/collapsible2</item>
</argument>
```

The path templates/collapsible2 should be

> app/code/namespace/module/view/adminhtml/ui-component/templates/collapsible2.xhtml

in app/code/namespace/module/etc/module.xml should add depend on Magento_Ui